# How to save the result of Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is part of a ruby script. I want to save the results to a text file. I only want the results specified in these two DIVS.

```
url = browser.html
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

price = doc.css("#sectionPrice").text
ship = doc.css("#shippingCharges td").text
```

How do I save the scraped results? Mind you that the script loading the page is working correclty. In `SHELL` I can see the values of my scrape using XPATH as follows.

```
page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
shipping = puts page_html.xpath(".//*[@id='shippingCharges']").inner_text
price = puts page_html.xpath(".//*[@id='sectionPrice']").inner_text
```

How do I save this data to a CSV or XML?

//Side Question: Is this data returned in `SHELL` saved anywhere? How do I access it outside of `SHELL`

```
url = browser.html
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

price = doc.css("#sectionPrice").text
ship = doc.css("#shippingCharges td").text

CSV.open("/users/fabio/desktop/ruby/gp.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [price, ship]
end
```

Not creating the `CSV`file. Nothing appearing in the `DIR` What gives?

Comment: For basic reading and writing data, you can use Ruby's `File` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple to write this to a csv file.

Just add the following in:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open("file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [price, ship]
end
```

If shipping and price are arrays then you will want to iterate through them but this is how you create a csv.

Hope this gets you on your way.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Sean, ty for the reply. I added your code to end of my script. Where is this file created?

Comment: Wherever you ran your ruby file from. You can also specify the path explicity. ie - CSV.open("/Users/sean/file.csv","wb") do |csv|

Comment: Hey tried setting the `path` and that didn't work either. --> see updated code

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? Maybe /Users/fabio/Desktop/ruby (it is case sensitive) For the binary, I don't remember why I started using binary mode, it fixed a problem one time and now I just default to it.